# BlockingQueue Blocks the Main Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

I am trying to run some multithreading in Java using LinkedBlockingQueue, but it seems the behavior is not as I am expecting. My main method is starting a new thread, who simply checks if the toSend queue is full. If it is not, then it simply waits till it is. In this context, I never add anything to it, but I still expect my main method to continue to the line after the creation of the thread and print the following line:

```
System.out.println("Multithreading continues as expected");
```

Eventually, my main method goes on to actually create another thread which will put packets into the toSend. However, it is not able to proceed past the creation of the thread. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("we are here);
    SendThread s = new SendThread();
    s.run();
    System.out.println("Multithreading continues as expected");
}

LinkedBlockingQueue<Packet> toSend = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
public static class SendThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Send Thread now active");
        while(true) {
            toSend.take();
            System.out.println("packet taken");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: s.start() That's how a Thread starts..!

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I have a couple of other threads that I use start() with, but just decided to use run() for some reason.